# Android x86 emulator extremely slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

At the moment I'm developing an application with Android wear support but I have no smartwatch. Now I want to test my application on an emulator but that is the problem. The emulator need up to 1.5 hours to start. I created one with following settings:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Target                 Google APIs (Google Inc.) API lev 22
CPU/ABI                Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Device                 5.1" WVGA (480x800: mdpi)
Skin                   No Skin

RAM                     512      //also tried with 768
VM Heap                  32
Internal Storage        200
Use Host GPU           true      //also tried with false
```

I installed HAXM, enabled it in the BIOS settings and if run

```
sc query intelhaxm
```

I get the status 4 like it is written [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows). I set the HAXM memmory to 2GB so it should be enought. I also do not run any other VM software and I have even reinstalled my Windows. The only interesting information from the LogCat is that there are many lines (up to 70%) of `Suspending all threads`

My computer has the following Hardware:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Windows 7 x64
Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600
8GB RAM
```

Do you have any ideas why my emulator is so slow?

**EDIT**: Here I posted the target for a smartphone device but it's also so slow for wearable devices so Genymotion is no real alternative because it has no images for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well dont know for sure but all the native emulator in android are very slow.

I suggest that you use the Genymotion which is very faster emulators for android than native.

It will give you user experience almost as of devices though it does have the same limitation of android native emulators.

Comment: Yes I know Genymotion but there are no images for wearable devices so this is one reason why I don't want to use it. Sorry I forgot this in my question - I've added it now

Comment: That's not true. The x86 emulators with HAXM should run very well. They did run on my PC fast untill last week or so. Now they run like the ARM emulators. Really annoying.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't answer to the question.  Answers not replying to the question should be banned on this site. Moreover there are strong suspicions that Genymotion slows down the computers when  it is installed, even when it is not running. This is probably due either by them directly installing malware etc, or by leaving security holes to such malware. Google a bit and you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: dude this was 5 year old ans. Of couse now native android emulators are fast with snapshot and all.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle your ScreenSize and Monitor dpi to get a lower scale - it will increase your speed of loading and usage..  SnapShot can also be Handy

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. One option is the Visual Studio Emulator for Android--it's fast, Hyper-V, x86, and free when you install Visual Studio 2015 (currently in Preview; free download).

Reference: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28417080/1904141)

2. Run Android Image in VirtualBox.
   http://www.android-x86.org/download
3. You can use the Intel x86 System images, I'm not sure but they might be faster

Note: I read somewhere that Anti Virus Softwares scan the Image of Emulator which make it slow. I need to confirm it.

Comment: Note that for Visual Studio Emulator for Android, your CPU needs to support SLAT. Oldel CPUs such as the one in this question (Intel Q6600) doesn't actually support it. Also, you need a Pro edition of Windows to use Hyper-V, at least when you're using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i figured out about a slow AndroidX86 in a VirtualBox...maybe it help you.
I have an older system. A Board with a P45Express chipset and only a dual core [E8400].

I have two 1 Gig LAN Ports on my Asus P5Q Deluxe Board [iam connected cia cable to my router]. One is working through the Northbrigde, the othe one works over a PCIe Lane. Since i use the PCIe Port, my AndroidX86 runs alot faster.
Before, when i used the NB supported port, it took me minutes to get a stable connection to the www. It looks like that the VM slows down hard, if the www connection is not supported by a good mainboard connection.
I dont use 3D accleration,i use VBoxSVGA and only PAE/NX and "Nested Paging".
Maybe that can help you abit.
Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score -1):

1.Make sure you are using 64-bit operating system.
2.Use host GPU while starting Emulator.
3.Update you graphic drivers if u have graphic card

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make the Android emulator faster and more responsive, you can configure it to take advantage of hardware acceleration. View this link for more details.

[Configuring Graphics Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try this configuration:

> - CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86);
>
>   - Device: Nexus 5;
> - Keyboard: Hardware Keyborard present;
> - Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls;
> - Ram: 2048;
> - VM Heap: 64;
> - Internal storage: 200 MB;
> - SD Card: 500 MB;
> - Emulation Options: Use Host GPU;

You have not described which IDE you are using for development. I use Eclipse and with this configuration the emulator go up very fast. Maybe if this won't fix your problem try to use Android studio and the relative emulator which should be better (with the same configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing the same issue and almost give up on learning android until I found Genymotion. It is highly recommended.

Answer (score -1):

One cause can be old HAXM driver:

Update here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Mine was very slow with 6.0.1 but fast with 6.1.1